# Tipue Search pretty URL

Tags: jquery, .htaccess

I try to do with the Tipue Search Jquery:

```
http://www.exemple.com/en/search/?q=blabla
```

to

```
http://www.exemple.com/en/search/blabla/
```

I change my Htaccess but not display the result and 404 error page :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\?q=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ en/search/%1/? [NE,L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ /en/search?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

My action form :

```
<form action="search/"> <input type="text" name="q"
class="input-block-level input-inverse" id="tipue_search_input"
autocomplete="off" required> </form>
```

Some ideas about the problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: Hi Starkeen. The htaccess is located on the root

Comment: Aren't you missing `/en/` in your form and in the last rewriterule?

Comment: Also, It seems that there are discrepancies in how you access the query string. In the URL you showed you have it as `/en/search/?q=xxx` but in the rewrite rule you have it has `/en/search?q=$1`. Notice you are missing a `/` after search. What is the correct query string for your URL?

Comment: Hi Pananma. The correct query string is `/en/search?q=$1`. I've added `/en/` in the form action and htaccess but nothing.

Comment: I tried this : `<form action="search.html">
<input type="text" name="q" class="input-block-level input-inverse" id="novaxxis_search_input" autocomplete="off" required>
</form>`   and my htaccess :   `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(en/search)/\?q=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [NE,L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(en/search)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/?q=$2 [NC,L,QSA]` and nothing. I have the pretty url `http://www.exemple.com/en/search/blabla/` but not show the result...